# How do we write non-ASCII characters to the STDIN of another process?

Tags: c++, named-pipes, 7zip

I have a code that writes a string to the STDIN of 7-zip process.

```
if (!WriteFile(hInput, string.c_str(), dwBytesToWrite, &dwBytesWritten, NULL)) {
   logger.error(L"write file failed", GetLastError());
   goto Cleanup;
}
```

This string is a password input to the stdin of 7-zip process. The code works fine (7-Zip process is able to extract the file successfully) if the password is all ASCII characters eg: Password@123. But it will fail if the password is @WSX3edcß, this code fails (7-Zip process gets the wrong password).

On a side-note, The password value is being read from a 3rd tool from command-line. Then this value is being passed over to a tool using a named-pipe. From which it writes to the 7-zip stdin.

Is there a way to pass non-ASCII string to the 7-zip process?

I have tried writing the wsrting to the stdin by the above convention, but doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "this code fails"? It returns zero and triggers `logger.error`?

Comment: Added. now will you remove the down-vote !? Didn't think that wasn't very obvious.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted. Also, may be relevant: https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/6ce5a6af/

Comment: Hard to guess, but a pipe and a stdin are transparent to any non ascii character. The problem could come from the way you read, store and process the password. You should log exactly what you have read and what you have tried to write.